# Why does derefenced pointer increment/decrement doesn't work?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

The following function is part of a [HackerRank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/post-transition/problem).
Why does the dereferenced pointer increment and decrement doesn't work? Please see comments.

```
void send_all_acceptable_packages(town* source, int source_office_index, town* target, int target_office_index)
{   
    int pkg_idx;

    post_office *src_office = &source->offices[source_office_index];
    post_office *tgt_office = &target->offices[target_office_index];

    volatile int *src_pkg_cnt = &src_office->packages_count;
    volatile int *tgt_pkg_cnt = &tgt_office->packages_count;

    for (pkg_idx = 0; pkg_idx < *src_pkg_cnt; pkg_idx++) {

        package *pkg = &src_office->packages[pkg_idx];

        if (is_acceptable(pkg, tgt_office)) {

            move_package(pkg_idx, src_office, tgt_office);
            pkg_idx -= 1;

            /* Start - This doesn't work */ 
            // *src_pkg_cnt--;
            // *tgt_pkg_cnt++;
            /* End */

            /* Start - This works */
            src_office->packages_count--;
            tgt_office->packages_count++;
            /* End */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Operator precedence again. You could drop postfix for prefix: `--*src_pkg_cnt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence.
You change pointers, not values pointed by them.

Should be:

```
   (*src_pkg_cnt)--;
   (*tgt_pkg_cnt)++;
```